# Rails asset pipeline on large iconset folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

It takes an incredibly long time (> 10min) to precompile assets since I have large iconset folders in vendor/images. This makes it really convenient for development since I have all those icons at my disposal but I use a very small number of them. For these small icons I use the asset_data_uri helper throughout my sass files.

Is there a way to have asset pipeline to not compile all of the images, and just the ones I use? Or if it could just not digest compile the images and only make them available for asset_data_uri?

Answer (score 0):

> Compiled assets are written to the location specified in
>   config.assets.prefix. By default, this is the public/assets directory.

You can update `config.assets.prefix` with your set of locations you want to precompile

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets